# Exporting PowerPoint as JPG end up with blurred texts

Tags: .net, vsto, powerpoint, apache-poi, office-interop

I'm developing a tool for exporting slides from a PowerPoint presentation to images and do some processing afterwards.

Currently I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint package to do the job. The problem is that it fails with all texts, leaving them all blurred.

It happens with presentation.SaveAs(fileName, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPNG, MsoTriState.msoTrue); as well with slide.Export(fileName, "PNG", width, height);

[This is how it should be](http://www.weka.com.br/pessoal/saulo/Slide1ShouldBe.PNG).
[This is how it end up being](http://www.weka.com.br/pessoal/saulo/Slide1.PNG).

Noticed that exporting the presentation whithin Powerpoint using "File > Save As" won't work either: texts are always blurred.

I've already tried to use [apache-poi](http://poi.apache.org/) and it does export the fonts correctly but won't work with all presentations I've tested (mainly because a bug on slides with grouped shapes).

There's a PowerPoint Add-In called [ImageExport](http://www.pptools.com/imageexport/index.html) from PPTools that works perfectly but I can't see a way to integrate it with my own software.

The only solution which seems to work so far is [Aspose Slides](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx). I just feel that is a cannon to kill a fly (because of the license price) as I only need to export slides as a full images and won't need any other feature.

Well, would be great to hear any advice, sample code, others libraries or tools which can be integrated with my own software that can help to export the slides as the really are.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested on MS Answers, your best best is to export to a considerably higher resolution than you need, then downsample the results to your final resolution.

There are various image processing libraries that you can use to do the downsampling.

FreeImage (available on SourceForge) is useful, well documented, well maintained and can be used freely.

That's basically what PPTools ImageExport does.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for you help again. As I've explained [there](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/why-save-as-jpg-end-up-exporting-slides-with/8c5f5602-dbb7-448c-9248-74cdf03311bf?tm=1320686335870&page=1#footer), although I haven't successfully downsampled the image yet, the first test looks promising.